# PostGIS installed, but unable to select version or add geography columns

Tags: postgresql, postgis, google-cloud-sql

I've got an existing Postgres 9.6 database on Google Cloud that has the PostGIS extension enabled, however whenever I try to create a table with a column with the `geography` type or select the PostGIS version I get an error.

For creating the `geography` column the error is non-descriptive — just an arrow pointing to the word `geography` in the following statement

```
create table place(coordinate geography(POINT,4326));
```

The version error looks as follows:

```
select postgis_full_version();
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.3": No such file or directory
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT postgis_lib_version()"
PL/pgSQL function postgis_full_version() line 22 at SQL statement
```

The `create extension` statement confirms it is already installed though e.g

```
create extension postgis;
error: the extension already exists
```

I've tried running these commands as the `postgres` user and as another user who's been granted permissions on the database in question but neither seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler than you think:
Your hosting privider has goofed up the PostGIS installation.

It looks like the file is *really* missing, or something else on the operating system level is misconfigured.

You should gripe at Google.