# When reading a table, got ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.3": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I have created a PostgreSQL database named 'datastore' in Google CLoud SQL by GCP for my application in PC and App.The version of Postgre server in cloud is 9.6. I communicate with this database to read stored tables using 'psql' client for Windows and Python Postgre library 'psycopg2'.
I communicate using 'psql' client using the following command:

```
PS D:\> psql -h <Db-IP-Address> -U postgres
```

Where 'Db-IP-Address' is IP Address assigned to 'datastore' by GCP. 
Following are some of tables in the 'datastore' :

```
postgres=> \dt
               List of relations
 Schema |            Name            | Type  |  Owner
--------+----------------------------+-------+----------
 public | company                    | table | postgres
 public | django_admin_log           | table | postgres
 public | django_content_type        | table | postgres
 public | django_migrations          | table | postgres
 public | image_data                 | table | postgres
 public | imagedata                  | table | postgres
 public | maggi                      | table | postgres
 public | storelocation2             | table | postgres
```

Until yesterday everything was working fine while reading/writing tables. But suddenly yesterday when tried to Read/edit table 'storelocation2'. It give the following error:

```
postgres=> \d storelocation2        
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.3": No such file or directory
postgres=>
```

ALso same happens in 'Select' command:

```
postgres=> SELECT * FROM storelocation2;
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.3": No such file or directory
postgres=>
```

While no such error comes when reading any other tables. The `'storelocation2'` table has data for store details like name, locations etc with variable defined as `'VARCHAR'` and one 'geography' point defined as `'geography(POINT, 4326)'`.

Please can anyone suggest what could be the possible reason and any remedy to get the table back. As it can lead to loss of huge data!!

Comment: Take a look to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52723460/postgis-installed-but-unable-to-select-version-or-add-geography-columns), seems related to an upgrade during this weekend

Comment: i followed your link and found that this can be a issue in the GCP side, so it means it cannot be resolved?? But i can read writ all tables except this particular one!!